# Is it bad practice to group all events in an application into one class?

Tags: c#, events

I'm working on a C# GUI application, and was wondering if it was bad form to group somewhat-unrelated events together JavaScript-style into one class as static events so subscribers don't need to get a reference to any of the objects responsible for raising them until they're raised. My reasoning is that that would extremely decouple the code, and keep a go-to reference for any events so I don't need to search for the object references, and if I need to refactor/rework some implementations later, their only big interface into the larger application is raising the event.

The events in question are global-ish in nature (i.e. view changed, asset was downloaded, etc) and are used mostly so view or controller objects can relay state changes/change content on the events.

Comment: Possibly better off over on [CodeReview.se](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: @Ben No no no no. This would be off-topic on Codereview because it contains no code.

Comment: @EthanBierlein that was my reasoning. I thought programmers.stackexchange, but just kind of defaulted to SO.

Comment: @EthanBierlein fair enough. I was going off the defnitions from [this meta post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266341/what-are-the-differences-between-stack-overflow-programmers-and-code-review) about the difference between SO, CR, and Programmers.

Comment: @Ben try [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/5777/23788) on CR meta :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pattern you are describing is a "Pub/Sub Architecture". Some objects push their events to a central location then some other objects subscribe from that central location and get notified as needed.

I would not recommend a beginner implement this system themselves because it is easy to make mistakes and cause objects to get unexpectedly rooted and unable to be garbage collected, leading to memory leaks.

I like to use [Prism's PubSubEvents library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Prism.PubSubEvents), its easy to use and does not cause memory leaks. See the "[Event Aggregation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122(v=pandp.40).aspx#EventAggregation)" section of the prism documentation for example useage.

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware of the garbage collection issue around static events keeping strong references to objects, so as I've started making sure I'm unsubscribing from the events as well - does that solve all the garbage collection issues around static events, or is there more to it than that? I come from more of an Objective-C background and haven't been with C# too long, so am still unfamiliar with how it does weak/strong referencing.

Comment: Unsubscribing handles it, you also can use WeakEvents via a [WeakEventManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.weakeventmanager(v=vs.110).aspx), that is what Prism is doing, just wrapping it up in to a more user friendly interface.